# p.adjust respect to whole dataframe

Tags: r

I have a dataframe of p.value with variable name for each column.

[image]

My code is `sapply(pval,p.adjust,method="fdr")`.

This code returns qvalue adjusted base on each column, which means p ranks based on each column then adjust.

How can I do the `fdr` with respect to the whole data frame, which means the p ranks among all data?

Answer (score 7):

This is not the most efficient way probably as it requires a lot of transformations but for small data.frames it should be fine:

example data (a data.frame of hypothetical p-values):

```
set.seed(100)
pval <- data.frame(a=runif(100), b=runif(100))
```

Now in order to calculate the the adjusted p-values I am using the `magrittr` package just to make it easier to read. You could essentially use nested functions:

```
library(magrittr)
pval %>% 
     as.matrix %>% 
     as.vector %>% 
     p.adjust(method='fdr') %>% 
     matrix(ncol=2)
```

Essentially, with the above you convert your data.frame to a matrix then to a vector then adjust the p-values according to all of the values and then re-construct the matrix.

The above could be written in base R as:

```
matrix(p.adjust(as.vector(as.matrix(pval)), method='fdr'),ncol=2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One alternative, which keeps row and column names, is to convert your squared matrix into a long matrix, compute the padj, and then convert it back:

```
longPVal=t(data.frame(row.names = c('G1','G2','R','P'), stringsAsFactors = F))

for(rr in rownames(pval)){ #Convert to long format (maybe MELT helps here?)
  for(cc in colnames(pval)){
    longPVal=rbind(fullSpear,c(rr,cc,dat1[rr,cc],pval[rr,cc]))
  }
}
longPVal[,'ADJP']=p.adjust(longPVal[,'P'], method = 'BH') #Correction

out=data.frame(stringsAsFactors = F) #Rebuild the squared matrix of adjP
for(rr in rownames(pval)){
  for(cc in rownames(pval)){
    rowdat=longPVal[which(longPVal[,'G1']==rr & fullSpear[,'G2']==cc),]
    out[rr,cc]=rowpos['ADJP']
  }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I come across this question.

check the Usage of p.adjust like following 
`p.adjust(p, method = p.adjust.methods, n = length(p))`

Actually, we can change the "n" to the length of the matrix, therefore, a simple apply should work in this way:

`pvalue_adjusted_matrix <- apply(pvalue,2,p.adjust,method="fdr", n = length(pvalue))`

Comment: From the docs: `Note that you can set n larger than length(p) which means the unobserved p-values are assumed to be greater than all the observed p for "bonferroni" and "holm" methods and equal to 1 for the other methods.`. I doubt OP wanted to have these assumptions